# Excel Worksheet.Cells doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, excel, cells, worksheet

I'm coding in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel objects.
This is my code:

```
var lastCell = xlsSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
xlRange = xlsSheet.Cells[lastCell.Row][lastCell.Column + 1]
```

In one case:

lastCell.Row = 22 and lastCell.Column = 21, but xlRange.Row = 22 and xlRange.Column = 23

or in other case

lastCell.Row = 23 and lastCell.Column = 23, but xlRange.Row = 24 and xlRange.Column = 23

What is going wrong?

Comment: @jon in the first case it should be: xlRange.Row = 22 and xlRange.Column = 22 and in the second: xlRange.Row = 23 and xlRange.Column = 24

Answer (score 0):

Excel rows and columns are indexed from 1 to n, rather than from 0 to n as an array (or indeed any ordered collection) would be. Could this be causing the confusion?